# Sort Value & Description Together Horizontally

Tags: vba, macros, sorting

I have a set of data listed horizontally where two cells work together with the value and description.

```
 A1   B1            C1   D1            E1   F1
 300  Description3  100  Description1  200  Description2
```

What I'm trying to do is sort horizontally based on the value, but I need to move the description with the value.

```
 A1   B1            C1   D1            E1   F1
 100  Description1  200  Description2  300  Description3
```

I know it's possible to sort this automatically with vba as it's entered if it's stacked vertically.  I'm wondering if it's possible to do it horizontally and have the description cell move with it.  If auto sorting isn't possible, is there a way to do it with a macro?

Comment: Do you always have exactly 3 entries like this sample or is it some other fixed number or is it variable? Do you need to sort them in place or is it OK to have it sorted somewhere else?

Comment: @Engineer Toast, in this particular form it'll have a fixed number, probably 4 entries.  Ideally I'd like to sort them in place rather than in another location.